# Is it possible to create an android.media.image instance from Bitmap?

Tags: android, image-processing

Working on face recognition but I cannot create Image class instance from the bitmap.

```java
croppedBitmap = BitmapHelper.decodeFile(new File(fileName), CROP_SIZE, CROP_SIZE, false);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
croppedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100 , stream);
Image myImg = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
```

Answer (score 2):

Image is an abstract class. You cannot create instances of it, and there are no concrete subclasses in the SDK.
Please find an alternate solution where you create "Image" object.